# How to add a script onLoad?

Tags: javascript, symfony1, onload

I have to add a Javascript onLoad on a tag  : I have a form and I want to disable an input at load.

How can I do this with symfony please ? I have to do this only for forms, so I can't add it in the tag  of the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the view.yml to add your js script only on the views containing forms. Like this:

```
yourViewSuccess:
  javascripts: [yourscript.js]
```

If you want to use the onload or onready, see this link : http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready

Comment: I know this, but after, How can I use <body onLoad='script'> ?

Comment: Your link is interesting but, I have try to use $(document).ready but it doesn't work.

(I have include jQuery)